# How to check the values contained in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

how to check the following values​​:

```
$var1 = x <= 100;
$var2 = 'P1, P2';
$check = array ($var1, $var2);
```

if there are data enter as below:

```
$input1 = 60;
$input2 = P2;
```

if the value `$input1` contained in the `$var1` it will be worth 1, and if the value `$input2`  contained in `$var2` it will be worth 1, if not then it is 0.
how do I look? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all I could guess you wanted, I think theres a certain language barrier, however.

```
$var1 = 100;
$var2 = 'P1, P2'

$input1 = 60;
$input2 = 'P2';

$check = 60 <= $var1 ? 1 : 0;
$check = strpos($var2, $input2) ? 1 : 0;
```